# TS1055 when using async/await using a type alias

Tags: typescript

I have declared a type alias:

```
export type ActivationPromise = Promise<void>;
```

I have written the following functions:

```
async function derp(): ActivationPromise {
    await test();
}

function test() : ActivationPromise {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [ "dom", "es5", "es2015.promise", "es2015.iterable", "scripthost"]
    },
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

When I compile, I get:

> error TS1055: Type 'ActivationPromise' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor

If I change the return type to simply `Promise<void>`, the code compiles fine. Only when using the type alias, the issue happens. Since the type alias should just function as a `typedef`, why does this happen?

Comment: There's an open issue for that: [type definition over async results](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14169) marked as bug.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> error TS1055: Type 'ActivationPromise' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor

## Suggestion

Refrain from type aliasing promises

## Fix

If you alias, make sure you have a [value backing it as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12776#issuecomment-265885846) which will be the mentioned `Promise-compatible constructor` instance:

```
export type ActivationPromise = Promise<void>;
export const ActivationPromise = Promise<void>;
```

Comment: Hoping that Typescript will fix this.